# Are Compression Couplings for Galvanized Steel Good for Long-term Repair?

Tags: plumbing, repair, pipe-fitting

Not a plumber. Did swap out some elbows on 1/2" steel water supply with some unions, couplings, and threading what I cut out. But I noticed there were [compression fittings like this on sale at the big box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southland-3-4-in-Galvanized-Iron-Compression-Coupling-Long-Pattern-160-004HP/304800282?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D26P-026_001_PIPE_FITTING-NA-NA-NA-SMART-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PMax&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D26P-026_001_PIPE_FITTING-NA-NA-NA-SMART-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PMax-71700000097492030--&gclid=Cj0KCQiA6fafBhC1ARIsAIJjL8n-UWr4OmErnk3TvZQDg79htd40cetUFMuca8IMs07bE4MkM8cRmBcaAq7ZEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). It would have saved me some threading work, but I was reluctant to veer away from threads and teflon worried that they wouldn't last. Is there a consensus on these sorts of fittings by plumbers? Are these things rated for long-term repair, and should I just skip cutting threads into the pipe next time and use them?

Comment: The description says for potable and non-potable water.  I have never used them. I always replaced any iron pipe. Not a plumber either.  I'll wait for one to answer.

Comment: I think they work on smooth pipe, so any threads would need to be cut off(unless you meant to cut threads).  Compression fittings are used on quite a few different types of pipe and should be good if the pipe is clean and smooth.  Dirt/burrs will defeat them/cause leaking.

Comment: The gimmick is replacing any galvanized steel waterline with the same, knowing the issues that they have. Stainless steel and plastics exist, it's not 1935, move on from 1935 era water pipe.

Comment: @Ecnerwal LOL Duly noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are sometimes called "repair couplings" or "Dresser couplings" and can be useful, although widely regarded as suitable only for a temporary quick fix. Probably not up to any plumbing code for new installations. If pipe is not restrained on both ends, it can be forced out of the coupling. No doubt they have saved somebody's bacon many times. Nothing "gimmicky" about that!

Comment: Thanks for putting it into words.